# C# WebResponse.GetResponse() returns System.Net.WebException on 404 page not found

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

I'm new to C#. I noticed that when the server returns anything other then 200 OK I get an

exception. Below is an example of 404 error.

**Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.**

Why should C# generate an exception?  This means that I have to use a try / catch block.

None of the examples I've seen mention this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to use a `try/catch` block because the GetResponse() throws an exeption for status codes in the range 4xx-5xx.

```
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    code = response.StatusCode;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    code = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: There does not seem to be response.StatusCode when I try to access the StatusCode inside the try block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it raises an exception. But you can still have the Response and Status from the exception object. So use try/catch, and get the info you need inside the catch block.

Comment: There does not seem to be response.StatusCode when I try to access the StatusCode inside the try block.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use try-catch, I suggest you read the following article: [Fixing WebRequest’s desire to throw exceptions instead of returning status](http://fearthecowboy.com/2011/09/02/fixing-webrequests-desire-to-throw-exceptions-instead-of-returning-status/).

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

or 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; //TLS 1.2
 or
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768; //TLS 1.1